# Installing Ubuntu to and running from an external HD without Live CD

Tags: installation, live-cd, external-hdd

I've got a 2TB external HD just for personal use, with an 8GB primary FAT32 partition (I made it there from the beginning just in case I wanted to install Ubuntu at a later moment)

Now I could probably figure out how to set it up using a Live CD, but unfortunately my DVD drive broke last week, and ATM I don't have access to a USB flash drive (I might tomorrow, but it's kinda time-bound)

Yep, I am pretty much a Ubuntu newbie.

Comment: This [guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/23/install-ubuntu-11-04-on-external-hard-disk/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wubi will install Ubuntu right from inside Windows.  You don't need a new partition because it will install as files on your Windows drive.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (installing on separate partition for better control tho)